# How to plot this bar graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have to create a script to analyse some data that are lists of lists (format is shown below). I have also attached a quick drawing of the bar graph format that I want to use to visualise the data.

Basically, I want a bar graph that plots each of the 6 data points inside each of the 10 lists in y_data. And they should be labeled from a to f, respectively.

I have tried two nested for loops that append each list value to another x temp and y temp lists and plot each, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I create this bar graph?

```
x_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

y_data =   [ [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],    
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],      
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ] ]
```

[image: Graph Format]

Here is one of my code attempts so far:

(The list of lists of lists is causing my confusion here!)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
y_data =   [ [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],    
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],      
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ],     
             [ [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60] ] ]

x_temp = []
y_temp = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(y_data)):
    for j in range(len(y_data[i])):
        x_temp.append(x_labels[j])
        y_temp.append(y_data[i][j])

ax.bar(x_temp, y_temp)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why is the y-data repeated? Isn't each just the bar height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want multiple sections of the same barplot that share the same x-axis labels.

Before this can be done, we have to make one small change to how you're creating `y_temp` (by the way, that's not a good variable name). Because `y_data` is structured as it is (I'm not sure why it is that way), you have to also index the first value otherwise you end up with 1-element lists (print out `y_temp` after the loop and you will see). So, the correction is:

```py
y_temp.append(y_data[i][j][0])
```

Now, for the plotting, you will want to first map the bars to unique values and then change the tick labels. This can be done by using `range` for the x-values and then `ax.set_ticks` to change them to the corresponding letters.

```py
ax.bar(range(len(x_temp)), y_temp)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(x_temp)), x_temp)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

So, in the end, only a couple of minor changes to your original code.

Comment: Thank you Jared, these code modifications work perfect. I notice your comment above, surely it is possible to not need x_temp as it just repeats the same characters a to f? Just loop through the x_labels list?

Comment: `y_temp` is not a good name because temp variables are typically used locally, but you are using it for plotting. If you want to use numpy, then you can get rid of the loops entirely. `x_temp = np.repeat(x_labels, len(y_data))` and `y_temp = np.asarray(y_data).flatten()`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I probably should have explained this in my question, but two more things:

Comment: 1. Is it possible to add a legend and colour code the bars for each of the x labels (i.e.e a = green, b = red etc)?

Comment: 2. I essentially am showing 10 different data samples for each of the 6 x-axis data points (a to f). Is it possible to number these data groups 1 to 10 on the x-axis below the a to f labels?

Comment: There are ways to handle this stuff. You should first search Stack Overflow because some of these have already been answered (for the coloring, you can do the same thing as with `x_temp` but for colors and pass them to the `color` `kwarg`). You might also want to look into using seaborn (a package built on matplotlib) which has more functionality. Seaborn often pairs well with Pandas.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake in my above comment. For the `x_temp`, `np.repeat` doesn't do what you want. Instead, you can do `x_temp = x_labels*len(y_data)`. (This also applies to the colors.)